AWS CodeDeploy fails AllowTraffic with 502
I hava 2 identical EC2 instances in a target group, with a load balancer in front. They have previously worked fine (one of them still do). When i use CodeDeploy to install a new version of my node.js application, the first instance it tries stays in AllowTraffic for a long time and is then deemed UNHEALTHY with a 502 (Bad Gateway) response.
I have a local nginx on the instance that forwards to my node instance. The nginx/node logs look great.
I've tried to make sure my instances are running ok by using curl in different ways:
Access node locally:
curl localhost:8082/healtcheck - response 200
Access via nginx:
curl -v --header 'Host: z.zzz.com' http://localhost:80/healthcheck - response 200
If nginx/node works, the load balancing works for the other target in my target group that runs the same setup, how should I continue to debug this?
